# Caching in Google App Engine/Cloud Based Hosting

Tags: google-app-engine, caching

I am curious as to how caching works in Google App Engine or any cloud based application. Since there is no guarantee that requests are sent to same sever, does that mean that if data is cached on 1st request on Server A, then on 2nd requests which is processed by Server B, it will not be able to access the cache?

If thats the case (cache only local to server), won't it be unlikely (depending on number of users) that a request uses the cache? eg. Google probably has thousands of servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With App Engine you cache using memcached. This means that a cache server will hold the data in memory (rather than each application server). The application servers (for a given application) all talk the same cache server (conceptually, there could be sharding or replication going on under the hoods).

In-memory caching on the application server itself will potentially not be very effective, because there is more than one of those (although for your given application there are only a few instances active, it is not spread out over all of Google's servers), and also because Google is free to shut them down all the time (which is a real problem for Java apps that take some time to boot up again, so now you can pay to keep idle instances alive).

In addition to these performance/effectiveness issues, in-memory caching on the application server could lead to consistency problems (every refresh shows different data when the caches are not in sync).

Comment: do you have any reference explaining the App Engine Topology with the cache server separated from the applications servers?

Comment: Well, they use memcached (that is in the offical docs). I do not know where that memcache runs (could be on the same physical machine as the application instance) and whether it is sharded or replicated. The important point is that it is not in the main process memory of the application instance, and that it is shared among all the instances (they all see the same cache contents).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of caching you want to achieve.

Caching on the application server itself can be interesting if you have complex in-memory object structure that takes time to rebuild from data loaded from the database. In that specific case, you may want to cache the result of the computation. It will be faster to use a local cache than a shared memcache to load if the structure is large.

If having consistent value between in-memory and the database is paramount, you can do some checksum/timestamp check with a stored value on the datastore, every time you use the cached value. Storing checksum/timestamp on a small object or in a global cache will fasten the process.

One big issue using global memcache is ensuring proper synchronization on "refilling" it, when a value is not yet present or has been flushed. If you have multiple servers doing the check at the exact same time and refilling value in cache, you may end-up having several distinct servers doing the refill at the same time. If the operation is idem-potent, this is not a problem; if not, a potential and very hard to trace bug.